# MySql Constraint Error at INSERT Statement in Detail Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, constraints

I have two tables (master/detail) in my MySQL 5 database. The master table is created like this:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `LEADERBOARD`.`GRUPO_PRODUCTO`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GRUPO_PRODUCTO` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NOMBRE` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `ESTADO` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The detail table is created like this:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `LEADERBOARD`.`DETALLE_GRUPO_PRODUCTO`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DETALLE_GRUPO_PRODUCTO` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PRODUCTO_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `GRUPO_PRODUCTO_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_DETALLE_GRUPO_PRODUCTO_GRUPO_PRODUCTO1_idx` (`GRUPO_PRODUCTO_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_DETALLE_GRUPO_PRODUCTO_GRUPO_PRODUCTO1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`GRUPO_PRODUCTO_ID`)
    REFERENCES `GRUPO_PRODUCTO` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I already have some rows in the master table, using these INSERT commands:

```
INSERT INTO `GRUPO_PRODUCTO` (`ID`,`NOMBRE`,`ESTADO`) VALUES (2,'Todos menos recargas','D');
INSERT INTO `GRUPO_PRODUCTO` (`ID`,`NOMBRE`,`ESTADO`) VALUES (3,'Todos menos recargas','D');
INSERT INTO `GRUPO_PRODUCTO` (`ID`,`NOMBRE`,`ESTADO`) VALUES (6,'Otros','D');
INSERT INTO `GRUPO_PRODUCTO` (`ID`,`NOMBRE`,`ESTADO`) VALUES (7,'Todos menos recargas','A');
```

But when I try to insert a row in the detail table referencing a row in the master table, I get the Integrity check constraint error:

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`leaderboard`.`detalle_grupo_producto`, CONSTRAINT
>   `fk_DETALLE_GRUPO_PRODUCTO_GRUPO_PRODUCTO1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`GRUPO_PRODUCTO_ID`) REFERENCES `LEADERBOARD`.`GRUPO_PRODUCTO` (`ID`)
>   ON DELETE NO A)

This is the INSERT command in the detail table (ID is omitted to use autoincrement):

```
INSERT INTO DETALLE_GRUPO_PRODUCTO (PRODUCTO_ID, GRUPO_PRODUCTO_ID) VALUES (13, 7);
```

Funny thing is, when I try to replicate the error in SQL Fiddle, it works without problems (I tried with MySQL 5.5.32 and MySQL 5.1.61 availables in the SQL Fiddle and it works in both of them): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbb4aa/2

What do you think my problem can be?

P.D. My database is a MySQL version 5.5.12 running on Mac OSX 10.9.3

Comment: Works perfectly here. Double check you actually successfully inserted to `GRUPO_PRODUCTO` with id=7.

Comment: @Fabricator I still don't know if it is a mysql specific version thing or a platform thing (Mac OSX) but I solved the problem regenerating the schema with CASCADE on the ON DELETE and ON UPDATE options for the foreign key. Isn't it weird?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved upgrading the MySQL database version from 5.5.32 to 5.6.19. After the upgrade, the problem never occurred again.